# How I can parse an array (from function) inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my `prg-ctrl.js`:

```
$scope.getDataOfProject = function(project, year){

    var projectData = project.data[year];
    var smthData = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {

        if (projectData[i]) {
            smthData.push(projectData[i]);
        } else {
            smthData.push(0);
        }
    }

    return smthData;
};
```

here is snippet of a JSON:

```
"projects": [
    {
    "id": 1,
        "data": {
            "2016": {
                "12": 18
            },
            "2017": {
                "1": 17.6,
                "2": 10.1,
                "3": 33.3,
                "4": 4.30
            }
        },
  .......
```

Then in `prj.html` file I have `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div ng-repeat="entity in getDataOfProject(project, 2016)">{{entity}}</div>
</div>
```

but my `<div class="col-md-9">` still empty. But when I put smth like:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div>{{getDataOfProject(project, 2016)}}</div>
</div>
```

I can see my data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you aware that indices start a 1 in JavaScript? You have a loop from 1 to 12 in function `$scope.getDataOfProject`.

Comment: if **project** is the json snippet you have posted, I have some questions: 1) Are you parsing the json from a string? where is it coming from? 2) the project variable is an array of objects. So you should loop `project` first to access each object and, then, access its properties (id, data ecc.).

Comment: @briosheje Thanks for your comment. At each time, I have only one project  to send it to the function.

Comment: @briosheje **project** (to send it to function) I got above in current html from the <div ng-repeat="project in model.projects">

Comment: @MaxGabderakhmanov: I have tried to replicate your project in a fiddle, and I've got it working. The only thing I've changed is that I have added a `track by $index` in the getDataOfProject for, since you might loop duplicate values. Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/591dy1yd/ . Also, I've added some strict type checks in the function so that if the year does not exists in the project object it won't crash.

Comment: @briosheje yes, it works! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I will post a little snippet below so that if someone needs it the answer is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that there might be duplicates in the array results, hence you may see a warning (or error) in the console. To avoid such, use `track by`:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div ng-repeat="entity in getDataOfProject(project, 2016) track by $index">{{entity}}</div>
</div>
```

Also, make sure you properly check whether keys exists in your original object:

```
$scope.getDataOfProject = function(project, year){
    if (typeof(project.data[year]) === "undefined") {
        return [];
    }
    var projectData = project.data[year];
    var smthData = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {

        if (projectData[i]) {
            smthData.push(projectData[i]);
        } else {
            smthData.push(0);
        }
    }

    return smthData;
    };
```